# Why my Firebase Realtime Database is only saving 1 user

Tags: android, database, firebase, authentication

Why my Realtime Database is not adding a new data, instead it is replacing just a new data. It must be adding not replacing.

This is my code for adding a new user:

```
public void addNewUser(String email, String username, String bio, String website, String interests, String address, String profile_photo){

    User user = new User(userID,1 , email, address, StringManipulation.condenseUsername(username));

    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users))
            .child(userID)
            .setValue(user);

    UserAccountSettings settings = new UserAccountSettings(
            interests,
            username,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            "",
            username,
            website,
            bio
    );

    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_account_settings))
            .child(userID)
            .setValue(settings);
}
```

The `User` class:

```
public class User {

private String user_id;
private long phone_number;
private String email;
private String address;
private String username;

public User(String user_id, long phone_number, String email, String address, String username) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
    this.email = email;
    this.address = address;
    this.username = username;
}

public User() {

}

public String getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public long getPhone_number() {
    return phone_number;
}

public void setPhone_number(long phone_number) {
    this.phone_number = phone_number;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "user_id='" + user_id + '\'' +
            ", phone_number=" + phone_number +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", address='" + address + '\'' +
            ", username='" + username + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

The `UserAccountSettings` class:

```
public class UserAccountSettings {

private String interests;
private String display_name;
private long followers;
private long truefans;
private long trustworthy;
private String profile_photo;
private String username;
private String website;
private String bio;

public UserAccountSettings(String interests, String display_name, long followers, long truefans, long trustworthy, String profile_photo, String username, String website, String bio) {
    this.interests = interests;
    this.display_name = display_name;
    this.followers = followers;
    this.truefans = truefans;
    this.trustworthy = trustworthy;
    this.profile_photo = profile_photo;
    this.username = username;
    this.website = website;
    this.bio = bio;
}

public UserAccountSettings() {

}

public String getInterests() {
    return interests;
}

public void setInterests(String interests) {
    this.interests = interests;
}

public String getDisplay_name() {
    return display_name;
}

public void setDisplay_name(String display_name) {
    this.display_name = display_name;
}

public long getFollowers() {
    return followers;
}

public void setFollowers(long followers) {
    this.followers = followers;
}

public long getTruefans() {
    return truefans;
}

public void setTruefans(long truefans) {
    this.truefans = truefans;
}

public long getTrustworthy() {
    return trustworthy;
}

public void setTrustworthy(long trustworthy) {
    this.trustworthy = trustworthy;
}

public String getProfile_photo() {
    return profile_photo;
}

public void setProfile_photo(String profile_photo) {
    this.profile_photo = profile_photo;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getWebsite() {
    return website;
}

public void setWebsite(String website) {
    this.website = website;
}

public String getBio() {
    return bio;
}

public void setBio(String bio) {
    this.bio = bio;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "UserAccountSettings{" +
            "interests='" + interests + '\'' +
            ", display_name='" + display_name + '\'' +
            ", followers=" + followers +
            ", truefans=" + truefans +
            ", trustworthy=" + trustworthy +
            ", profile_photo='" + profile_photo + '\'' +
            ", username='" + username + '\'' +
            ", website='" + website + '\'' +
            ", bio='" + bio + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

This is where I call the method of `firebaseMethod.addNewUser`:

```
 mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

                myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        // 1st check: Make sure the username is not already in use
                        if (firebaseMethods.checkIfUsernameExists(username, dataSnapshot)){
                            append = myRef.push().getKey().substring(3,10);
                            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: username already exists. Appending random string to name: " + append);
                        }

                        username = username + append;

                        // add new user to the database

                        firebaseMethods.addNewUser(email,username,"","","","","");

                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Signup successful. Sending verification email.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                finish();

            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };
```

This is my `mAauth.signOut`in `HomeActivity.class`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting.");

    setupFirebaseAuth();

    initImageLoader();
    setupBottomNavigationView();
    setupViewPager();

    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();


}
```

Image for Authenticated users:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRq8K.png)

Image for Database:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSQgO.png)

> Sorry for not posting the images, just do not have enough rep. Thank you

Comment: It looks like you are overwriting data in the database or something similar. You might want to add some code showing how you save the user in the database.

Comment: No you can add multiple user or display their functionality in firebase.You might have done something wrong while adding the user id to firebase which will be clarify after you add your code snippet

Comment: I just added the codes. Thank you!

Comment: Where does the userID come from in the addNewUser function? Also It would make it more clear if you focus on one part, for example only adding user and ignoring (removing atleast from here) the accountsettings part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase allows to store information of multiple users in firebase realtime database but only as authenticated users. I think you have not signout from your first user. That is why, its saving only one user. Have you created a signout button and have you done something like this :

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuth.signOut();
```

Comment: Yea i did that. I just improve my question. Pkease check my codes, thank you!

Comment: where is your signout method. I don't see it? Post full code its hard to understand with only chunks of code that you are showing.

Comment: if you have uploaded code in github, provide the github link

Comment: I still do not have the signout method yet, but I added the code for signing out.

Comment: implement the signout method. you have to authenticate user before entering details since you are using authID of the user to store the data. if you have added it then show us the code. provide the full code, not half baked code.

Comment: I just fixed it, and now adding the new user data but it is adding a new nodes not in my want. This is my new question about my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50925599/adding-data-in-the-realtime-database-but-it-adding-in-the-wrong-child thank you!

Comment: was my answer helpful??

Comment: It just some issues again after adding new users hehe

Comment: ok, I will look into your new query. If my anwer was helpful. Please upvote my answer and mark correct to it. Thank you.