# Adding Data in the Realtime Database but it adding in the wrong child

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add new user data under the `userId` but instead it is replacing the old data into new data and adding another "users" and "user_account_settings".

This is my Realtime Database: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWppf.png)

My Realtime Database must be like this: adding a new user data without replacing old datas into new datas and also not adding "users" and "user_account_settings".

This the example of database structure I want : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB4xr.png)

This is the code for adding new user:

```
public void addNewUser(String email, String username, String bio, String website, String interests, String address, String profile_photo){

    User user = new User(userID,1 , email, address, StringManipulation.condenseUsername(username));

    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users))
            .child(userID)
            .child("users")
            .push()
            .setValue(user);

    UserAccountSettings settings = new UserAccountSettings(
            interests,
            username,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            "",
            username,
            website,
            bio
    );

    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_account_settings))
            .child(userID)
            .child("user_account_settings")
            .push()
            .setValue(settings);
}
```

This is the code where I call the `firebaseMethods.addNewUser` from the `RegisterActivity.class`:

```
 private void setupFirebaseAuth(){
    Log.d(TAG, "setupFirebaseAuth: setting up firebase auth.");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

                myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        // 1st check: Make sure the username is not already in use
                        if (firebaseMethods.checkIfUsernameExists(username, dataSnapshot)){
                            append = myRef.push().getKey().substring(3,10);
                            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: username already exists. Appending random string to name: " + append);
                        }

                        username = username + append;

                        // add new user to the database

                        firebaseMethods.addNewUser(email,username,"","","","","");

                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Signup successful. Sending verification email.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                finish();

            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };
```

This is my data structure now , Frank van Puffelen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZX7d.png)

Comment: How is this different from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907820/why-my-firebase-realtime-database-is-only-saving-1-user)? (Except from adding a second problem)

Comment: My other question is already solved and now is adding new user data but the location of the new user data saving in is in the "`path`, `to`, `data`" as you seen in the image in top. It must be like this,  the new user data must be located under the `userId` without replacing other datas. Just like example picture.

Comment: If your other question is fixed then why is the 2nd scenario here exactly the same issue as in that other question?

Comment: Just not all the same. I will remove all my question and add the new problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing to the wrong location in these snippets:

```
.child(userID)
.child("users")
.push()
```

This leads to a path `/$uid/users/-L....`, which is not what you want. You instead want the path to be `/users/$uid`, which means your code needs to match that:

```
.child("users")
.child(userID)
```

So with that your `addNewUser` becomes:

```
public void addNewUser(String email, String username, String bio, String website, String interests, String address, String profile_photo){

    User user = new User(userID,1 , email, address, StringManipulation.condenseUsername(username));

    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users))
            .child(userID)
            .setValue(user);

    UserAccountSettings settings = new UserAccountSettings(
            interests, username, 0, 0, 0, "", username, website, bio
    );

    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_account_settings))
            .child(userID)
            .setValue(settings);
}
```

Comment: I apply your answer but still getting same result, it is just change the location between of "users" / "user_account_settings" and the "`userId`". It also replacing the old datas to new datas.

Comment: I added the picture of my data structure now after I apply your answer. Thank you!

Comment: If i remove the .child("users") and .child("users_account_settings") i will get my data structure that i want but still replacing the old datas into new datas.

Comment: I updated the code in my answer to remove the duplicate `/users/users`. The code is expected to replace the existing value for the user. But the [screenshot you posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONJWM.png) also only has one set of data for each user, so I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: I replace my picture of the sturcture base i want, it is more specific. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add data under `userid` then do this:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("userid");
```

Then the location will be the `userid` and any data you add will be under it.

Comment: Where should I add that, sir? And should I remove the `getReferencefromUrl` ?

Comment: yes remove getReferenceFromUrl and add the line of code in the answer instead of it. Then when you want to add data just do `ref.setValue("myData")` or `ref.child("name").setValue("name_here");`

Comment: What do you mean the answer? I think i should do that in `addNewUser` method?

Comment: instead of this `myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://my-app-e37d8.firebaseio.com/path/to/data");` use `DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("userid");`

Comment: Yea i did it. But still a bit wrong. I will add the result i got by picture in my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line above :

> myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://my-app-e37d8.firebaseio.com/path/to/data");

and do something like :

> myRef.child("users").child(userId).setValue(YourClass.class);

**put your class name instead of YourClass**

or if you are storing only string then just do :

> myRef.child("users").child(userId).setValue("Hello World");

Comment: Where I will add that?

Comment: after : userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

Comment: And if I will add that, I have 2 class, how to do it?

Comment: 2 classes for what??

Comment: The "users" node and "user_account_settings" node

Comment: first of all, why are you keeping two nodes for storing user details?

Comment: I already did your answer, but still getting same result. It is still replacing the existing data to new data

Comment: which data is replacing? data of the same user or different user??